# Find number in string and replace it

Tags: linux, shell, sed, perl, awk

I wrote C++ code and now I want to replace the number in a string by using shell scripts.

The part that needs to be replaced:

```
if (random<=90)
```

How I can change the 90 from a shell script?

I wrote this but I need something efficient other than `sed` or with a better regular expression just to match the number itself.

```
for i in {1..1000..100}
do
sed -i "s/(random<=.*)/(random<=$i)/g" myfile
done
```

Comment: @slhck i working with NS3 and ns3 is linux based simulator that use C++ file to build network. and every time i need o change some network parameter i need to change the c++ file(edit was made for question)

Comment: by the way i think this is not XY problem because the C++ file is just for building the results not for calculation and all af calculations done with shell scripting. could you plz help me with this?

Comment: I know NS3. I think it'd be easier if you could just pass arguments to the C++ file instead. Anyway… what is the real question? Your script works, doesn't it? The only thing wrong with it is that it will always overwrite `myfile` until you end up with `random<=901` at the last iteration.

Comment: @slhck how could i replace just number? and what tool do you offer to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to match the number, you need [positive lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `sed` does not support this, but `perl` does.

```
perl -pi -e "s/(?<=\(random<=).*(?=\))/$i/g" myfile
```

To explain:

```
(?<=                         positive lookbehind
  \(random<=                 match a literal (random<=
)
.*                           match any character, multiple times
(?=                          positive lookeahead
  \)                         match a literal )
)
```

The lookbehind and lookahead matches are not used, so you can replace with `$i`.

Comment: i think you are the father of linux :)

Comment: Problem solved!